# React Native Sticky Header using react-native-tab-view

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-tab-view

I'm trying to implement sticky header with tabbar in React Native. So when user scroll down, the header will collapse, and when scroll up, it will expand again. 
But, I got a problem with **blank space**, if we move to an unscrollable tab. Also, I can't get the collapsed header back.

Screencast: https://gfycat.com/MelodicIncomparableAlpineroadguidetigerbeetle

```
Screen code: https://pastebin.com/pUNaT6Qt
```

Any solution/idea for this? TiA.

Comment: Hi, I would like to know have you figure this out yet?